# Border around bars and caterories, ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to plot a bar plot in ggplot, having as y number of animals per species by  on x the countries. I manage that far, but as I try to outline each species and bar I get the border between each value in the graph.

I also tried using the reprex package to create a nicer looking question including my graphs, but I have too little reputation to post the pictures apparently.

So I try the code only:

create dataframe

```
library(tidyverse)

country <- c( "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "CC", "CC", "DD", "DD", "EE", "EE")
sheep <-c(130, 146, 12, 15, 19, 0, 44, 57, 99, 123)
cattle <- c(11, 34, 221, 0, 91, 49, 33, 28, 19, 10)
pigs <- c(55, 0, 34, 48, 54, 0, 33, 59, 112, 23)

animals_wide <- data_frame(country, sheep, pigs, cattle)
```

'reshape' the table from wide to long (tidyr::gather)

```
animals_long <- animals_wide %>%
  gather(key = species, value = numbers, -country)

glimpse(animals_long)
```

plot by ggplot

```
ggplot(animals_long, aes(country, numbers, fill = species)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray", "black", "white"))
```

[image]

tries to add black outline to 'species' in bar by adding geom_bar(..., colour = "black)

```
ggplot(animals_long, aes(country, numbers, fill = species)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray", "black", "white"))
```

[image]
So, what I would like to achieve is a bar plot with a black border of each of the species. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should be able to post the image now.

Comment: if still you cannot upload the image please upload it in some other space in web, and add the link here to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the country appears twice in your data frame, hence two values for each species. therefor, you have to combine both values to get one black border in your plot.

thats easy achieveable with:

```
 animals_long <- animals_long %>% 
   group_by(country, species) %>% 
   summarise(numbers = sum(numbers))
```

which leads to

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I missed the summarise! Perfect.